# How to train custom model opeennlp?

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I wanted to train my own custom model.
From where can I start?

I am using this sample data to train a model:

```
<START:meaningless>Took connection and<END>  selected the Text in the Letter Template and cleared the Formatting of Text to Normal.
```

Basically I wanted to identify some meaningless text from the given input.

I tried with following Sample Code given on opennlp development docs
But getting error: **Model not compatible with name finder!**

```
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
ObjectStream<String> lineStream =
        new PlainTextByLineStream(new FileInputStream("mynewmodel.train"), charset);
ObjectStream<NameSample> sampleStream = new NameSampleDataStream(lineStream);

TokenNameFinderModel model;

try {
  model = NameFinderME.train("en", "meaningless", sampleStream,
      Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap(), 100, 5);
}
finally {
  sampleStream.close();
}

try {
  modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(modelFile));
  model.serialize(modelOut);
} finally {
  if (modelOut != null) 
     modelOut.close();      
}
```

Comment: one question what kind of file is "mynewmodel.train"??

Answer (score 0):

Likely problem: you're not presenting the trainer with clearly tokenized text. The PlainTextByLineStream, if I understand the documentation correctly, requires whitespace-delimited tokens. So

```
<START:meaningless> Took connection and <END>
```

rather than

```
<START:meaningless>Took connection and<END>
```